# Convert Theta ERC-20 to Theta Main Network

Tags: wallet, exchanges

As a test, I transferred one Theta ERC-20 token to my new Theta web wallet, and I see it there.  How do I now convert it to the main net Theta?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On another site, someone reported this: 
Your actual theta tokens are in the wallet where your ERC20 tokens were at time of the deployment of the theta blockchain. You have to get the private key for that wallet and open it on the theta web wallet site to gain access to not just your theta but also your tfuel.

My response and results:

I would have never guessed I could logon to an old ETH wall from the Theta Wallet.

Worked great, much easier than I thought. I was guessing I would have to ask them to convert it.

My ERC-20 Theta tokens were on Exodus, and unfortunately Exodus has not added support yet for Theta.  In that wallet you are able to show your private/public key for Ethereum. 
With that, I was able to logon to Theta wallet with my private key from Exodus and see my coins and TFuel, then I just transferred them to my newly created Theta wallet.

Comment: Ledger Nano used to support the Theta ERC20 token. Does it now also support the new non-ERC Theta token?

Comment: I don't know, don't use a Nano yet.